# Behaviour of background-clip: text

Tags: html, css

In the example below, `background-clip: text` seems to disable the overflow of `div`. What's happening here? It also disables the scrollbar if you give `div` one.

```css
html {
  font-size: 100px;
}

div {
height: 300px;
width: 300px;
border: 10px solid red;
color: transparent;
background-color: gold;
overflow: scroll;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-clip: text;
-webkit-background-clip: text
}
```

```html
<div>I am a div. Lorum ipsum Lorum ipsum Lorum ipsum</div>
<section>Lorum ipsum Lorum ipsum Lorum ipsum Lorum ipsum</section>
```

Comment: there is an overflow but transparent, the background cannot color outside